# Micromax Canvas 2 Restarting Problem. Show modem log on the way?

Tags: contacts, 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, call-history

I got sick of this.

Whenever i restart my phone it shows "Modem log on the way". I don't know what type of log they are but it creates a folder in my internal storage named "mtklog" which contains some other folders like "mdlog","mobilelog" and "configlog".

The size of these folders are approx 1GB. It gets all over my internal storage. If i delete this folder or stop the process "Modem log on the way", my phone doesn't displaying any contacts and call logs.

And the most important thing after this so called "log" process gets over the contacts in my phone memory gets duplicated.

Please help if any one has solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did u try disabling it from System UI Logger screen ?

Comment: yup if I disable the logging my contacts are not displying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
     formating your device that will solve your problem regarding to      restarting device sucessfully.

I hope above solution will help you.